# regex to extract all that in quotes

Tags: regex, parsing, csv

I am trying to write a regex to match all strings which appear in between enclosing characters  (most likely `"` - double quotes). This is a scenario I commonly encounter while trying to parse a line in a csv file.

So I have a sample line like:

```
"Smith, John",25,"21/45, North Avenue",IBM
```

Tried the following regex:

```
"(.*)"
```

But it fetches somewhat as follows:

[image: http://regexr.com?37ie3]

I am expecting output as follows:

```
Smith, John
25
21/45, North Avenue
IBM
```

The regex I have written is an attempt to capture what comes between `"` in my example. However, above is the output I am expecting.

There is a kind of ambiguity though: I am not looking for a match like: `,25,`. This kinda makes me wonder if a regex is even feasible here.

What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: `"([^"]*)"` or `"(.*?)"` will work but it will create another problem.

Comment: In what language will you use the regex?

Comment: @SalmanA can you explain the problematic scenario...

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte c# mostly...

Comment: @deostroll: I see two problems:1) you must deal with a capturing group, 2) you must deal with escaped quotes.

Comment: I would rather use a good CSV parser library instead of using RegEx. The problem is that  `John Smith,25,"21/45, North Avenue",IBM` and `"John ""Microsoft Guy"" Smith",25,"21/45, North Avenue",IBM` are both valid examples of CSV data.

Comment: @SalmanA: And all of these are correctly matched by the regex I proposed. Actually, the CSV file format lends itself quite well to analysis by regular expressions. It gets problematic as soon as you have to deal with *malformed* CSV (like an unequal number of fields per line, incorrectly matched quotes etc.) where a parser would be able to error out, whereas a regex would most likely start matching incorrect portions of the input, masking such errors in ways that may be difficult to detect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to roll your own CSV parser, you'll need to teach your regex a few rules:

1. A field may be unquoted as long as it doesn't contains quotes, commas or newlines.
2. A quoted field may contain any characters; quotes are escaped by doubling.
3. Commas are used as separators.

So, to match one CSV field, you can use the following regex:

```
(?mx)       # Verbose, multiline mode
(?<=^|,)    # Assert there is a comma or start of line before the current position.
(?:         # Start non-capturing group:
 "          # Either match an opening quote, followed by
 (?:        # a non-capturing group:
  ""        #  Either an escaped quote
 |          #  or
  [^"]+     #  any characters except quotes
 )*         # End of inner non-capturing group, repeat as needed.
 "          # Match a closing quote.
|           # OR
 [^,"\r\n]+ # Match any number of characters except commas, quotes or newlines
)           # End of outer non-capturing group
(?=,|$)     # Assert there is a comma or end-of-line after the current position
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/yM9sI3).

Comment: Are you sure that quotes will be escaped with .net style?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I would not worry too much about the target language and how certain required characters are escaped. Perhaps even the quoting character may vary...i.e. it may not be `"`; it could be `'` instead, or whatever punctuation...bottom line its not something I'd worry about...

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Well, at least that's what CSV encoders usually do. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples - but I wouldn't rule out other approaches.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Indeed! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use regex for this, CSV should be handled by a parser.

Here is a ready-to-use parser: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

You can also use the OLEDB built-in parser:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-using-the-built-in-oledb-csv-parser

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that will only capture one group. Secondly, you need to be non-greedy:

```
(?:"(.*?)")
```

This does not solve your problem of multiple matches in a single line.
Here are two examples:

```
import re
string = '"Smith, John",25,"21/45, North Avenue",IBM'
pattern = r'(?:"(.*?)")'
re.findall(pattern, string)
> ['Smith, John', '21/45, North Avenue']
```

In C#:

```
string pattern = @"(?:\""(.*?)\"")";
string input = @"\""Smith, John\"",25,\""21/45, North Avenue\"",IBM'";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) 
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
```